# After ajax request in IE8 give this error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I have one function in js, in chrome work ok,. but not working in IE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function save () {
                                $.ajax({
                                url: 'somepage.aspx',
                                data: {
                                    cmd: "add",
                                    },
                                type: 'POST',
                                async: true,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                                // somelogic

                                }
                            });
                        }
 </script>
```

in Chrome work ok, but in ie give this error:

**SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.**

**jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2 character 11497**

thanks in advance

I forgot to delete **,** I had several variables in data 
data:{ cmd:"add", itemId: $("#someInputId").val(),anotherId: $("#someInputId2").val()}
**Edited:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function save () {
                                $.ajax({
                                url: 'somepage.aspx',
                                data: {
                                    cmd:"add", 
                                    itemId: $("#someInputId").val(),
                                    anotherId: $("#someInputId2").val()
                                    },
                                type: 'POST',
                                async: true,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                                // somelogic
                               }
                            });
                        }
 </script>
```

Comment: remove `,` in `cmd: "add",` and an extra `}`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña I deleted but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: you updated your script, now you're missing a `}` in success

Comment: Seems okay to me , just one more question do you have that `//somelogic` in your script? if yes please delete comments `//` `<!-- -->` in your ajax script. See if it works

Comment: @DrixsonOseña no in succes I have one 'if',  if (data.Success == true) {}else{}

Comment: That's weird your syntax are correct and that should be okay in your browser. Do you mind removing `cache: false,` I had this similar problem before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma after "add" in the data object.  IE doesn't like this a lot of the times.

It also looks like there is some syntax errors.. the extra brace in the success handler for one.

Try this:

```
function save() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'somepage.aspx',
        data: {
            cmd: "add"
        },
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            // some logic
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you didn't remove the extra `,` in data

Comment: thanks! forgot to remove that when I was cleaning it up right after I mentioned it.  Doh!